# Device uses non-USB charger. Can I still charge it through the USB port?

Tags: charging, tablet

I got a [Polaroid L9H tablet](https://southerntelecom.com/polaroidsupport/downloads/L9H-32.pdf) for Christmas, which includes a carrying case with built-in USB keyboard. I assume that it is for this reason that the tablet was designed with a barrel connector for its AC/DC adapter, rather than the micro-USB charging I'd come to associate with all modern portable electronics.

I tried to locate technical specifications for the tablet, but could only find the mini-pamphlet provided by the manufacturer, which says nothing either way about this:

If I plug this device into one of the many USB chargers I have distributed throughout my house, will it:

- not charge at all?
- charge, but not as rapidly as when using the provided adapter?
- maybe charge, but probably also damage the tablet?
- drain the battery even faster than being unplugged?
- ruin the USB port?
- explode?

I would really like to know if I can safely plug this tablet into my other chargers, or if I will be forced to bring the manufacturer's cord wherever I take the tablet.

Comment: Why not simply connect it to a PC via USB and see? After all, that's what the USB port is for. Let us know then whether the PC exploded :)

Comment: I've seen many older phones and cameras with data only USB connection, i.e. you can use it to transfer files and photos but no recharging.

Answer (score 1):

Being on safe side, my guess is **No**, you can't charge (no, it won't explode but just won't charge) since

1. User pamphlet shows only way of charging
2. The USB port may be **data only** not charging and data. Yes, those kind of ports do exist and you can read [How USB Charging works](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/115251-how-usb-charging-works-or-how-to-avoid-blowing-up-your-smartphone)

Having said that, I don't see any logic for having a port that does not charge. It has a 4500 mAh , which is typical and can be charged through USB
Port. There is no reason to have a "data only" port, unless manufacturer has form factor/manufacturing cost constraints. It is actually "odd" to encounter such ports in present day devices

**Edit 1**

Looks like my guess was right!

**Edit 2**

Apologies for quoting the wrong product in support of my answer.Fact is that L9H is not covered in FAQ and as OP pointed out, he is unable to register product so product support seems to be way behind

Yet, [Polaroid Support Site](http://southerntelecom.com/polaroidsupport/user_guides.html) lists out user manuals for your device in [16GB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4qzt97h9dmbxpc/L9H16.pdf?dl=0) and 32 GB version

OP had linked in his question user manual which corresponds to **32GB and dies not show USB charging, and shows only mains charging**

User manual of **L9H 16 GB shows clearly USB Port being used for charging from power pack in addition to mains charging**

**Conclusion**: OPs model is not supported for USB charging, for reasons mentioned earlier (data only USB Port and user manual **not** mentioning USB charging as an option)

OP can further reach out to the OEM to get additional clarification if needed, but that may not be warranted

Comment: @izzy. Interesting , this is the first time I have  across this type of "non charging port" on a tablet, though remember seeing on some earlier laptop of a colleague..

Comment: I've got a Visual Land Prestige Elite 10Q that has *two* USB ports -- one is for charging *only*, and has no data connection (as far as I've been able to determine), the other is for the keyboard (and presumably other data devices), and won't accept charging.  Conversely, my previous tablet, a Lenovo (I've forgotten the model number) used Bluetooth for the keyboard and had a conventional (for Android devices) data-and-charge USB port.

Comment: I left an answer there.  Not sure how much help it'll be...

Comment: That FAQ is for the PMID700, which is not the same model. It also says that the tablet doesn't have access to the Google Play Store (but calls it the "Google Android market"). The LH9 does have the Play Store preloaded on it, so I can't accept that FAQ as an authoritative answer for this device.

Comment: Note also that the Polaroid Support site doesn't have an FAQ at all for the L9H tablet, nor firmware, or any other resource than the user guide. It's not even available as a model number to select on the [registration form](http://southerntelecom.com/Joomla/register-form-polaroid)!