# Charge and USB keyboard through 1 USB port

Tags: samsung, usb, charging

I have a Samsung Tab E that only has one USB port.

Can I charge the tablet and have a USB keyboard attached at the same time?

I've tried a 3-way cable ( [link to Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00EB70PQW?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01) ) but it supplies power to the keyboard, not the tablet.

I've also tried using a USB hub I had lying around, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Samsung support and their answer was that the single USB port cannot be used for charging the tablet at the same time as providing a data connection.

Comment: That was what I pointed out in my answer too !

Answer (score 4):

The most likely way to use a keyboard while charging on a single port device is to use a *Bluetooth* keyboard.

Failing that, you may need a different 3-way cable.  The keyboard certainly needs power to operate (unless it has internal battery power), but a correctly wired 3-way cable should be able to *both* power the keyboard and charge the device.  You can verify that there's voltage on the charge pins of the two USB connectors on the 3-way cable, with a meter and suitable fine probes -- though it's very possible that the device will refuse to accept charge if there's a data attachment on the USB port.  You'd have to contact Samsung to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

There are three kinds of USB ports in use (before USB Type C)- data only, charge only and both data and charge

Quoting from [How USB charging works](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/115251-how-usb-charging-works-or-how-to-avoid-blowing-up-your-smartphone)

> In terms of actual current (milliamps or mA), there are three kinds of USB port dictated by the current specs: a standard downstream port, a charging downstream port, and a dedicated charging port. The first two can be found on your computer (and should be labeled as such), and the third kind applies to “dumb” wall chargers.

[Tablets are known to have any of these ports](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132832/device-uses-non-usb-charger-can-i-still-charge-it-through-the-usb-port/132872#comment166494_132872). The port you have for charging is a dedicated charging port (as I suspect ) and will not allow simultaneous data transfer. This is borne out by your observation that the keyboard is getting power when connected with a 3 way cable or even USB hub (more reliable for such requirements)

You can easily verify this by connecting a flash drive through an OTG cable and transfer files. If it doesn't work (as I suspect), you have your confirmed answer

It may turn out to be a futile attempt by introducing additional hardware to meet your goal if the port itself cannot support. You may like to first validate this by seeking a confirmation from OEM, in case my reasoning current appeal to you